# Keep getting error of Identifier already declared

Tags: node.js

Pardon me for the bad questions, as i just started with SQL yesterday. I'm trying to get the server up and running but i keep getting the error of

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'gamesDB' has already been declared

Which i have no idea what it means. Can anyone help me out?

```
"use strict";

var gamesDB  = require('../models/gamesDB');

const gamesDB = new GamesDB();

function getAllGames(request, respond)
{
    gamesDB.getAllGames(function(error, result)
    {
        if (error) {
            respond.json(error);
        } else {
            respond.json(result);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = { getAllGames };
```

Comment: MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server are two different products. Which one are you using?

Comment: Agree with tadman... And while you [edit] the question to fix that, you may want to remove the [tag:visual-studio] tag, whose description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."*

Comment: can you please edit your question and post the full code?

Comment: Its alright i solved it, there was a variable not in capital letter. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define a variable and a constant with the same name in these lines:

```
var GamesDB  = require('../models/gamesDB');

const gamesDB = new GamesDB();
```

Change one of the variable names and it should work as expected.

Comment: Having changed const gamesDB to const gamesDB1.

 It says "gamesDB1 is declared but its value is never read". Making the function unable to work.

Comment: change your code to mine (I editted the answer). Just changed the first GamesDB to a capital G. it should now work as expected.

Comment: The const gamesDB is still "declared and its value is never read" and the 

GamesDB.callGames(function(error, result) is "any".  Sorry for bad english and formatting.

Comment: Its alright i solved it, there was a variable not in capital letter. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I literally told you to change to capital letter :D anyway, happy to help