# My discord js command handler not working

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey i can't seem to get my command handler to work with multiple command file could someone help me with this i tried multiple ways i can't seem to get it to work with multiple folders. I'm a bit new to Discord js as well i had one working then i wanted to make it more organized and i can't seem to get it to work

```js
const fs = require(`fs`);

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./moderationcommands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of command_files) {
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`, `../moderationcommands/${file}`);
        if (command.name) {
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error

```js
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\handlers\command_handler.js:5
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./moderationcommands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
          ^

SyntaxError: Identifier 'command_files' has already been declared
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\main.js:13:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\main.js:12:38)
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep getting error of Identifier already declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010322/keep-getting-error-of-identifier-already-declared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named two variables exactly the same:

```js
const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./moderationcommands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

You just have to make sure, that they have different names

Comment: yea i know that but even if i was i tried and it still would not work im wondering how i would make it with 2 different directory's

Comment: You could wrap your `for-loop` in a function and call it with './commands/' and './moderationcommands/'

Comment: wait nvm i got it to work i changed the name of the varable and added a nother for...

to it

Comment: Also, your `else statement` is not necessary :D If `command.name` is empty or undefined, the loop will continue anyways

Comment: ahhh alr sorry im a bit new to this start about 2 weeks ago